# OpenAM : Cross Domain HTTP Status 404 - / appagent / sunwCDSSORedirectURI

Tags: openam

I deployed `OpenAM` with cross domain but when I tried to view has sample application agent `tomcat`, after authenticating the server `OpenAM` he returns `404 error`:
`HTTP Status 404 - / appagent / sunwCDSSORedirectURI`

Status report types

`message / appagent / sunwCDSSORedirectURI`

description The requested resource (`/ appagent / sunwCDSSORedirectURI`) is not available.

note: in my page `sunwCDSSORedirectURI.jsp` agent deploy on `tomcat` contains no treatment is that it is normal ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy the 'agentapp' as well ... documentation is your friend 'http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam-pa/3.1.0-Xpress/agent-install-guide/index.html#chap-apache-tomcat' section 9.2, step 7

Comment: Slight correction, you need to either enable the global filter mode of the agent, or deploy the agentapp.war on Tomcat. If you are still experiencing errors with the previous URL, then you might have some strange issues with cookies (the cookie that would store the originally accessed URL gets lost), run liveHttpHeaders and see if you send the amFilterCDSSORequest cookie with your request.

Comment: thanks its works, i just remove the tomcat agent policy and install it